# Include MathJax support in CS Theory's Blog

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, blog-overflow, rendering

MathJax is not being rendered in the [CS Theory blog](http://cstheory.blogoverflow.com/).

(Confirmed on OsX G.Chrome and OsX Firefox.)

Maybe MathJax is not a feature in (BlogOverflow or just CS Theory blog).  So, please include it in the CS Theory blog.

---

From the comments, it has been explained that the images are externally hosted.

Comment: Dunno  about Latex (maybe it's not supported there by design) but the images are not SE fault, they are external, e.g. http://web.mit.edu/abhatt/www/fig4.png.

Comment: Those images are externally hosted. wayback machine still have them: http://web.archive.org/web/20131205005136/http://web.mit.edu/abhatt/www/fig1.png

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks for pointing out. I'll edit the post to rant about just the Latex then :)

Comment: It doesn't look like they include the MathJax js lib

Comment: @rene is correct, guess they don't think it's required in blogs, so better change this into a feature request.

Comment: Seems to be working fine on [math.se's blog](http://math.blogoverflow.com/). A cstheory mod or SE employee could probably check the MathJax-Latex settings in the dashboard.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It is, in the Math blog(arjafi's comment beat mine :) ). so, changed the qn as a feature request for the CS Theory blog.

Comment: That many posts include correct MathJax formatting for the blog (`$latex...$`) suggests that MathJax rendering was enabled at some point, and has somehow been switched off.  Indeed, from [the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20121203172539/http://cstheory.blogoverflow.com/2012/02/something-you-should-know-about-quantifier-elimination-part-ii/) we get MathJax loaded (though nothing actually renders properly, which is probably a Wayback Machine problem). That would seem to make this a bug as opposed to a feature request.